# What are some tips for a PVE/PVP Gunslinger build in Aura Kingdom?

Tags: aura-kingdom

I was wondering how I should allocate my offensive (damage, critical hit, accuracy) and defensive (HP, defense, evasion) stats for my Gunslinger. Currently, I'm focusing primarily on building critical hit for offense but, I'm not too sure what defensive stats I should focus on. I'm leaning towards pumping up HP/Defense but, looking through the official forums, I'm not too sure about the viability of it during late to endgame.

Moreover, I was wondering what would be a viable secondary class. I'm currently interested in Wizards, Sorcerers, and Grenadiers, and would like to know the pros and cons of taking one as my subclass.

Thanks again folks!

Answer (score 1):

in build pure crit is good your damage depend on your weps and same goes to acu. and the 
-CD there is a gem for that

in def. go pure eva..thats the only thing i can think of now

Comment: Hmm... I understand Crit but, why EVA. I thought it drops off in usefulness in higher levels compared to HP and/or defense.

Answer (score 1):

You will need high eva in pvp there are just a few players who build on acc (secret stone's, core's) they will just miss on you, try to cap eva (95% to cap it)